# Order Product Validation Rule

Tags: validation, order, orderitem

Is it possible to add a Validation Rule to Orders which checks a certain product name has been added to the order?

Basically the price book includes products a, b and c.  If the user selects a certain field on the order then I need to ensure AT LEAST product b is added to the order.  The easiest way to do this is to validate that a product exists on the order with the name like "removal".

I have failed so far and I have tried these:

- Adding a Roll Up Summary field on Order Items.  This didn't work as product name isn't available. I would then validate that this roll up summaries count was > 1.
- Adding an order product Validation Rule on the product name and order field.  This didn't work as it fired when adding products a and c and these can be legitimately added to the order.
- Apex trigger on orderitems, I didn't get too far with this as I struggled with the logic.

Is there a recommended approach to validating order products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add the product name as a criterion in any rollup helper tool. I am most specifically familiar with [`Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries`](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries), which is certainly capable of crafting the rollup  you need.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to DLRS is to do the following:

- Create a custom field on OrderItem called `Product_Name__c`
- Create a workflow that populates `OrderItem.Product__c` with the value of `OrderItem.PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductCode`
- Use standard RollupSummary field on Order (since OrderItem is master-detail) to count the number of `OrderItem.Product__c = 'B'` into a number field
- Then you can use a Validation Rule on Order.

Personally, I like DLRS because it has better expressive power and doesn't involve this trick of avoiding cross-object fields in RSF criteria. For orgs that have well-written existing triggers, adding DLRS shouldn't be an impact.